# Exclude weekends from date/time hour count

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

I have the following which works fine for my needs:

```
function funLoad(str1,str3,str4)
{

    var dym1 = str1.split("/");

    var d=new Date();
    var dym2 = d.getMonth() + 1 + "-" + d.getDate() + "-" + d.getFullYear() + " " + d.getHours() + ":" + d.getMinutes() + ":00";
    //var dym2 = "6 10 2013 09:00:00";

    var start = Date.parse(dym1[1] + "-" + dym1[0] + "-" + dym1[2] + " " + str3 + ":" + str4 + ":00"); 
    var end = Date.parse(dym2);

    return (start-end) / (1000*60*60);

}

$("#btn1").click(function(event){
    alert(funLoad($("#txt1").val(),$("#ddlHourTime").val(),$("#ddlMinuteTime").val()));
});
```

Here is a jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/QTVWd/8/

I appreciate that this will probably only work in IE8, but I'm developing in an intranet environment where everyone only uses IE8, so that's not an issue.  Ignoring that, this script just gets the selected date and time, compares it with the current date/time, and returns the hours.  All good so far.

The problem is that it counts the weekends.  How do I only count hours on weekdays and exclude the weekends if the start and end date include weekends?  So for example, if the start date is on a friday, and the end date is on a monday, it should only count the hours on friday and monday, excluding the 48 hours on the weekends.

Comment: Please be aware that not every day is 24 hours long, assuming daylight savings time is in effect in the used timezone (since we are talking specifically about weekend days here, there are two saturdays in a year that are problematic). As far as I can see from a quick look, none of the answers so far account for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function I worked up in jsfiddle should do what your looking for.  You'll want to run it through it's paces to ensure it is calculating everything correctly.

[updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eq7cj/7/)

function funLoad(str1, str3, str4) {

```
var dym1 = str1.split("/");

// get the given(start) epoch value (using midnight for time - will adjust for actual time further below)
var start_date = new Date(dym1[2], (dym1[1]-1), dym1[0], 0, 0, 0, 0);    
var start_epoch = start_date.getTime();

// get todays(end) epoch value (using midnight for time - will adjust for actual time further below)    
var end_d = new Date();
var end_epoch = new Date(end_d.getFullYear(), end_d.getMonth(), end_d.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0).getTime();
var end_date_is_weekend = (end_d.getDay()==0 || end_d.getDay()==6)?1:0;    

// get value for 1 day in milliseconds
var one_day = 1000*60*60*24; 

// how many days between given date and todays date
var total_days = Math.ceil( (end_epoch - start_epoch ) / one_day)-1;

// figure out how many of those total days are weekend days
var date_to_check = start_epoch + one_day; 
var total_weekend_days = 0;
var next_day_is_weekend = 0;
for(var x=0; x<total_days; x++){
    d=new Date(date_to_check);
    if(d.getDay()==0 || d.getDay()==6){
        total_weekend_days++;
        if(x==0){next_day_is_weekend=1;}
    }
    date_to_check += one_day
}

// determine number of week days
var total_week_days = total_days - total_weekend_days;

// get the total hours from the total week days
var total_hours = total_week_days*24; 

// still need to add the remaining hours from the given(start) date and the number of hours that have already past in the end(todays) date

// add in the remaining hours left in the start date
var hours_remaining_in_start_date = 0;

// rounding up to next nearest start date hour
if(str4 > 30){
    if(str3 == 23 && next_day_is_weekend==0){
        // rounding up puts the start date into the start of the next day so subtract
        // one day from the total, UNLESS the next day is a weekend.
        total_week_days -= 1;

        hours_remaining_in_start_date = -24;

    }else{
        hours_remaining_in_start_date = 24 - (str3+1);                       
    }
}else{
    hours_remaining_in_start_date = 24 - str3;        
}    

total_hours += hours_remaining_in_start_date; 

    // add in the hours from the end date (today date), UNLESS today is a weekend
var hours_past_in_end_date = 0;
var end_hour = end_d.getHours();
if(end_date_is_weekend==0){
    // rounding up to next nearest end date hour
    if(end_d.getMinutes() > 30){
        if(end_hour == 23){
            // rounding up makes it a full day
            hours_past_in_end_date = 24;
        }else{
            // rounding up just adds an hour
            hours_past_in_end_date = end_hour+1;
        }
    }else{
        hours_past_in_end_date = end_hour;    
    }
}
total_hours += hours_past_in_end_date;



$('#result').html('start epoch:'+start_epoch+', end epoch:'+end_epoch+', total days'+total_days+', total weekends'+total_weekend_days+', total week days:'+total_week_days+', hours_remaining_in_start_date:'+hours_remaining_in_start_date+', hours_past_in_end_date:'+hours_past_in_end_date+', total hours:'+total_hours);
```

}

Comment: First jsfiddle link went to something awful.  Just updated it to point to the right place.  Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
var calcWorkHours = function calcWorkHours(start, end) {
        var total = (end - start) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24),  // compute difference in days
            totalDays = parseInt(total, 10),                // trim fractional portion
            remainder = (total - totalDays) * 24,           // save fractional portion in hours
            startingDay = start.getDay(),                   // starting weekday
            endingDay = end.getDay(),                       // ending weekday
            possibleWorkingDays = (totalDays * 5),
            actualOccurringWeekends = (startingDay - endingDay) * 2,
            workDays = (possibleWorkingDays - actualOccurringWeekends) / 7;
        if (endingDay === 6) {
            workDays -= 1;  // ends on a weekend, subtract a day
        }
        if (startingDay === 0) {
            workDays -= 1;  // starts on a weekend, subtract a day
        }
        return (workDays * 24) + remainder; // convert to hours and add back fractional portion
    },
    parseInputs = function parseInputs(date, hour, minute) {
        var dmy = date.split("/"),
            now = new Date(),
            thisMinute = now.getMonth() + 1 + "-" + now.getDate() + "-" + now.getFullYear() + " " + now.getHours() + ":" + now.getMinutes() + ":00",
            start = Date.parse(dmy[1] + "-" + dmy[0] + "-" + dmy[2] + " " + hour + ":" + minute + ":00"),
            end = Date.parse(thisMinute);
        start = new Date(start);
        end = new Date(end);
        return calcWorkHours(start, end);
    };
```

See it in action here: **http://jsfiddle.net/QTVWd/9/**

**UPDATE**

If you really need the hours expressed as a negative number, just switch the parameters in `calcWorkHours`:

```
return calcWorkHours(end, start);
```